# how to add dates from option value in setDate

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the difference date from my input from and the client can determine the how many days. After that it will calculate after i choose "1 days" or "2 days", and show the result of addition dates in my input with "to" as an id.

setdate didn't add correctly from my option value. I'm using getDuration to retrieve the value in option. I assume that variable can add my setDate.

```
<select name="duration" id="duration" class="form-control" onchange="run(this.value)">
<script>
function run(val) {
    var formDuration = document.getElementById("duration");
    var getDuration = formDuration.options[formDuration.selectedIndex].value;
    // alert(getDuration);

    document.getElementById("from").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = new Date(this.value);
    var newdate = new Date(input);
    var temp = newdate.getDate();
    var calculate = temp + getDuration;
    newdate.setDate(calculate);
    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy =  newdate.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
    } 
    if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
    } 
    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    document.getElementById('to').value = someFormattedDate;
    });
}
(function() { 
    var elm = document.getElementById('duration'),
        df = document.createDocumentFragment(); 
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { 
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = i;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + " days")); 
        df.appendChild(option);
    }
    elm.appendChild(df); 

}()); 
</script>
</select>
```

dates in this format : mm/dd/yyyy

example 1
from : 07/01/2019
duration : 1 days
to : 07/11/2019

example 2
from : 07/02/2019
duration : 1 days
to : 07/21/2019

example 3
from : 07/03/2019
duration : 1 days
to : 07/31/2019

expected results

from : 07/01/2019
duration : 1 days
to : 07/02/2019

Comment: Try edit: `var calculate = temp + parseInt(getDuration);`

Comment: @Chaska it works.. haha thank you bro